# How to 'format' a list in python

Tags: python

Let's say i have a list that looks like this:

```
myList = [4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7]
```

How can I format it so it looks like this

```
myList = [4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to remove the duplicates.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set